# Show sub menu via hook_menu

Tags: 7, routes

Sorry for asking such a question, but I'm still new in Drupal. I want to show sub menu via main menu.

```
Ex:
- Top menu
1) Home
  a. Report
  b. Comment
2) Shopping
  a. Audi
  b. Honda
```

In this case, I would like to see 'a. Audi, b. Honda', or go back Home and see 'a. Report, b. Comment'.
What should my module's hook_menu implementation look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by using the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module.

> Superfish integrates jQuery Superfish plugin with your Drupal menus.

Image from Superfish module page

[image]

There is another module called [Nice Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

> Nice Menus enables drop-down/right/left expandable menus. It uses only CSS for most browsers, with minimal Javascript for IE6. (Version 2 uses the Superfish jQuery plugin for all browsers, with an option to disable JS, and falls back to CSS-only for browsers that can handle it.)

Comment: I'm thinking that OP asked about hook_menu implementation, not for a solution with the Superfish (similar) module.

Comment: @Kartagis Yes I know, but I think we can suggest an alternated for that(Previously some moderators did so). That's why I mentioned "you can simply achieve that" in my post and moreover OP didn't mention any code part here.